# JsReport & Handlebars. How to Place today's date?

Tags: handlebars.js, jsreport

Working with Handlebars and JSReport to setup a "Mail Merge" of sorts. I want to put the Date the mail merge was performed on each.

JSreport allows Javascript and JSON for data and logic, but I'm having trouble getting it going properly. I did try to set a new Date object for the template to pull, but I don't get the value of the date object on the page.

I tried to add `var today = new Date(Date.now());` and then `{{today}}` to the template, but I literally get {today} on the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare helper function at the bottom part of the jsreport studio as

```
function now() {
    return new Date()
}
```

And then at the upper part use it as

```
{{now}}
```

Adapt the helper to your formatting needs...
[Demo here](https://playground.jsreport.net/studio/workspace/BkzXTOdSM/2)